# Disabling asp Controls using .attr does not work in FF & Chrome, Whereas it works with IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Here is what i am using to disable the controls on click of a button:

```
$('#cmdbtnreleaseOwner').attr('disabled', true); 
$('#cmdlnkbtnreleaseOwner').attr('disabled', true);
```

This disables the controls with respective ids in IE, but doesn't works with Mozilla FF and Chrome..

Edit:

Here is my Aspx code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="cmdbtnreleaseOwner" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/add-prospect.png" CommandName="Release" OnClientClick="return OnServiceOrderButtonClick();" />

 <asp:LinkButton Text="Release OwnerShip" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" ID="cmdlnkbtnreleaseOwner" CommandName="Release" OnClientClick="return OnServiceOrderButtonClick();" />
```

HTML from Source :

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ServiceOrderGridView$ctl00$ctl02$ctl00$cmdbtnreleaseOwner" id="cmdbtnreleaseOwner" src="../images/add-prospect.png" onclick="return OnServiceOrderButtonClick();" />

<p>
<a onclick="return OnServiceOrderButtonClick();" id="cmdlnkbtnreleaseOwner" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ServiceOrderGridView$ctl00$ctl02$ctl00$cmdlnkbtnreleaseOwner&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Release OwnerShip</a>
</p>
```

Comment: You should use .prop() for this http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: I am using 1.2.6 version, i have also tried updating my JS to 1.7.2 and .prop is not working..

Comment: works for me in chrome21, FF12

Comment: .prop() is not working after an update? Have you made sure that the older jQuery library was not cached?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `prop()` instead:

```
$('#cmdbtnreleaseOwner').prop('disabled', true); 
$('#cmdlnkbtnreleaseOwner').prop('disabled', true);
```

This is assuming these elements support the `disabled` property of course.

Comment: Yes, it do support disabled property as IE disables it.. And .prop is also not working, i have tried after updating my JS from 1.2.6 to 1.7.2

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the HTML of the elements you are trying to disable.

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML which the browser sees.

Answer (score 3):

As Rory says, or:

```
$('#cmdbtnreleaseOwner').attr('disabled', 'disabled');  
$('#cmdlnkbtnreleaseOwner').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Works in IE and the rest - the `.prop` is in my opinion the better way to go.